# What type of characters are these and how to decode?

Tags: apache, character-encoding, decode, mod-security

So, just as the title says above is related to the fact that I just implemented mod_security and I would like to decode logs results like:

`\\xe7\\xa9\\x80\\xe7\\x94\\xb0\\xe6\\x81\\xb5\\xe4\\xba\\x8c`

Just to know what's blocking

More data

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2).
>
> Pattern match **"(^[\"'`\\xc2\\xb4\\xe2\\x80\\x99\\xe2\\x80\\x98;]+|[\\"'`\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98;]+$)"**
>
> at ARGS:search_query. [file "/etc/apache2/mod-security modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf"] [line "64"] [id "981318"] [rev "2.2.5"]
>
> [msg "SQL Injection Attack:
> Common Injection Testing Detected"] [data "\xe2"]
>
> [severity "CRITICAL"] [tag "WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-19"]
> [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A1"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/CIE1"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"]
>
> [hostname "www.site.com"] [uri "/results"] [unique_id "UBREwh@DH6YAAGY0LjMAAAAE"]

Hope this extra information results useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be just about anything. Without context, my guess would be that it’s Chinese characters in UTF-8 encoding converted to text by replacing each byte by \x and the value in hex.

Comment: I've append some more data, maybe that will help

Answer (score 2):

These are UTF-8 code units. Remove the \\x of each byte and use this website to find out: http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/

So you need to put this **e7 a9 80 e7 94 b0 e6 81 b5 e4 ba 8c**
below in the site in the UTF-8 Code Unit textfield and get this result above in the Characters field:

**穀田恵二**

It's japanese, meaning **Keiji Kokuta**.

As of Wikipedia:

> Keiji Kokuta (穀田 恵二 Kokuta Keiji?, born January 11, 1947) is a
>   Japanese politician and member of the House of Representatives for the
>   Japanese Communist Party.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like ASCII in hexadecimal format to me